# Python: Quiero leer una serie de datos de un .txt, realizar una serie de calculos y guardar los resultado en otro achivo

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un archivo de texto como este:

```
material1;1200;44
material2;1200;44
material3;475;44
material4;508;44
fin
```

Y quiero extraer las líneas de texto de a una de modo de que cada dato quede como un elemento de una lista para luego realizar una serie de cálculos.
Este es mi código hasta ahora:

```
# calcular cuántas barras de un material de una cierta longitud necesitas para fabricar x barras de y longitud cada una, 
# y cuántos retazos (pedazos sobrantes) te quedan después de la fabricación.

longitud_barras = 12000 #longitud barras de material en milimetros

#abro archivos
archivo_datos=open('datos.txt','r')
archivo_resultado=open("resultado.txt", "w")

#inicio ciclo
while(archivo_datos.readline != "fin"):
    #divido linea leida en una lista
    datos = archivo_datos.readline().split(";")
    #asigno una variable a cada dato en la lista
    tipo_material = str(datos[0])
    longitud_material = float(datos[1])
    cantidad_material = float(datos[2])
    #realizo los caculos
    cantidad_una_barra = longitud_barras/longitud_material
    cantidad_barrars = round(cantidad_material/cantidad_una_barra)
    retazos = cantidad_material - cantidad_una_barra
    retazos = longitud_barras - (retazos*longitud_material)
    #escribo los resultados en resultados.txt
    archivo_resultado.write(str(tipo_material)+" "+str(longitud_material)+" "+str(cantidad_material)+" "+str(cantidad_barrars)+" "+str(retazos))

#cierro archivos
archivo_datos.close()
archivo_resultado.close()
```

Al ejecutarlo me da un error en la línea 18 que dice:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\prueba.py", line 16, in <module>
    longitud_material = float(datos[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?
¿Cómo podría mejorar mi programa para hacerlo funcionar?

Logré hacer funcionar una versión de este programa que en lugar de leer los datos desde un archivo, estos son ingresados por el usuario, pero la cantidad de datos es demasiado grande como para que esto sea práctico. Estoy usando python 3.9.4 si ayuda en algo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es porque el programa intenta acceder a los elementos datos[1] y datos[2] en la linea final y esos elementos no existen.

Una solución sencilla con la que conservarías todo tu código seria añadir una condición en el while, algo como esto:

```py
while(archivo_datos.readline != "fin"):
    lineas = archivo_datos.readline().split(";")
    if "fin" not in lineas:
        #divido linea leida en una lista
        datos = archivo_datos.readline().split(";")
        #asigno una variable a cada dato en la lista
        tipo_material = str(datos[0])
        longitud_material = float(datos[1])
        cantidad_material = float(datos[2])
        #realizo los caculos
        cantidad_una_barra = longitud_barras/longitud_material
        cantidad_barrars = round(cantidad_material/cantidad_una_barra)
        retazos = cantidad_material - cantidad_una_barra
        retazos = longitud_barras - (retazos*longitud_material)
        #escribo los resultados en resultados.txt
        archivo_resultado.write(str(tipo_material)+" "+str(longitud_material)+" "+str(cantidad_material)+" "+str(cantidad_barrars)+" "+str(retazos))
    else:
        break
```

Sin embargo, podrías reescribir tu código para que sea más eficiente, legible y te de un resultado universal. Podrías hacer algo como esto:

```py
import json
longitud_barras = 12000

with open('datos.txt','r') as archivo_datos:
    lineas = archivo_datos.readlines()

resultados=[]
for linea in lineas:
    if linea.strip() != "fin":
        datos = linea.split(";")
        tipo_material = str(datos[0])
        longitud_material = float(datos[1])
        cantidad_material = float(datos[2])
        #realizo los caculos
        cantidad_una_barra = longitud_barras/longitud_material
        cantidad_barrars = round(cantidad_material/cantidad_una_barra)
        retazos = cantidad_material - cantidad_una_barra
        retazos = longitud_barras - (retazos*longitud_material)
        resultados.append({tipo_material:{"longitud_material":longitud_material,"cantidad_material":cantidad_material,"cantidad_barrars":cantidad_barrars,"retazos":retazos}})

with open("resultado.txt","w") as file:
    json.dump(resultados, file, indent=2)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Estaba seguro de que había una mejor manera de resolver el problema, al principio intente hacer algo similar al segundo ejemplo, pero me salia un error similar, pensé que estaba haciendo algo mal entonces decidí usar el ciclo mientras, ya que estoy mas familiarizado con la estructura de ese ciclo.